# Name of a 1970's ESP/Psychic-themed "docudrama" series?

Tags: story-identification, tv, psychic

**Plot Summary/Details**

This one was a quasi-documentary style show that I believe was supposed to be based on (supposedly) actual real life occurrences of the paranormal. It wasn't, as best as I can remember, meant to be a fictional show in the vein of Twilight Zone or Outer Limits.

I recall one episode where a woman gets a premonition or other psychic warning about a dangerous man that will try to hurt her and/or her sister in the future.  The story's finale has her using martial arts to beat her attacker up (I seem to recall a finishing blow involving a high-heeled kick/stomp) and escape with her younger sister.  There is a narration at the end about the power of ESP or something.

**Timeframe/Production Details**

I saw the show in the late 70s.  1977-1979 seems the most likely window.

The show looked rather low budget, and it may have been shot on video tape, rather than film. It sticks in my mind it was a syndicated show, though I cannot be certain.

I'm positive it was not the British series *Leap in the Dark*, which ran in the UK around that time.

Comment: I'm posting as a comment rather than an answer because I can't answer the martial arts point, but could it be The Omega Factor? It was also British, released in 1979 (so in your timeframe) and paranormal themed. Playlist at https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx0uoaCus0a-cpM5i5LvPC2d9N6TI-k84 which may jog your memory!

Comment: If it's not The Omega Factor, could check the archived list of "telefantasy" shows from various countries [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324215202/http://homepage.ntlworld.com/john.seymour1/telefantasylist/whatistelefantasy.html), just click 1970s and pick a year.

Comment: @Peter That's not the show I was looking for, but it does look quite interesting!  I'll have to give it a watch.

Answer (score 10):

This show might be "The Sixth Sense", from the early 1970s.
The description below is from Wikipedia.

The Sixth Sense is an American paranormal thriller television series featuring Gary Collins and Catherine Ferrar. The series was produced by and filmed at Universal Studios, and broadcast by ABC from January 15 to December 23, 1972.

The Sixth Sense series was based on the 1971 television movie Sweet, Sweet Rachel.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fhhp.jpg) That opened with a photo of UCLA's Royce Hall—implying UCLA is where Dr. Darrow is a parapsychology researcher — and with a quote: "'If I had my life to live over, I should devote myself to psychic research rather than psychoanalysis.' — Sigmund Freud."

Its cast included Alex Dreier as Dr. Lucas Darrow (former surgeon and parapsychology researcher), Pat Hingle as Arthur Piper, Louise Latham as Lillian Piper, Steve Ihnat as Dr. Simon Tyler (Psychologist), Brenda Scott as Nora Piper, Chris Robinson as Carey Johnson (Dr. Darrow's blind research assistant), Stefanie Powers as Mrs. Rachel Stanton, Rod McCarey as Paul Stanton, Richard Bull as Lt. Fisher, Mark Tapscott as Henry, John Hillerman as Medical Examiner, William Bryant as Doctor and John Alvin as Surgeon. It was produced by Stan Shpetner, written by Anthony Lawrence and directed by Sutton Roley with music by Laurence Rosenthal. It was filmed at Samuel Goldwyn Studios.

Synopsis:

Dr. Michael Rhodes (Collins), a professor of parapsychology who has ESP, and his assistant Nancy Murphy (Ferrar) attempt to solve supernatural crimes and mysteries.

[image]

Comment: That's a good guess, but the show I saw was in the late 70s, and was supposed to be based on real-life psychic happenings, rather than an ESP-themed dramatic series.  Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2):

I've found other paranormal-themed television shows from that period, and "Unknown Powers", from 1978, seems best to match your specifics of real life psychic events. I do not personally recall the show. IMDb indicates that the program may have been a one-shot - a documentary that consisted of three episodes of a cancelled TV series.
The show was directed by Don Como, and hosted by Jack Palance, Samantha Eggar, and Will Geer.
I've been unable to determine which network aired this show.

[image]